# Error creating new slice using gpart on FreeBSD

Tags: vps, freebsd, partition, zfs, gparted

The virtual hard disk of one of my VPS has been enlarged, and I want to create a new ZFS slice using the extra space, but I couldn't be able to perform that.

```
# gpart add -s 10G -t freebsd-zfs da0
gpart: Invalid argument

# gpart show
=>      63  31457160  da0  MBR  (15G)
        63  10474317    1  freebsd  [active]  (5.0G)
  10474380  20982843       - free -  (10G)

=>       0  10474317  da0s1  BSD  (5.0G)
         0   9216000      1  freebsd-ufs  (4.4G)
   9216000   1258317      2  freebsd-swap  (614M)
```

Answer (score 4):

This simply means that your /dev/da0 is not of the new "**GPT**" partition scheme, but of the old "**MBR**" partition scheme.

As from "man gpart", under the "PARTITION TYPES" section, you would see that there are no "zfs" related partition type for "**MBR**". Just use the "**freebsd**" type instead:

```
gpart add -s 10G -t freebsd da0
```

Then use the created "/dev/da0s2" device into your zfs.

By the way, why wanting to create a zfs from just 1 slice ? Would another ufs partition not being enough (my 2 cents) ?